# ¿Cómo puedo enviar la información de un Editext en un chat con un botón ademas de usar android:imeOptions="actionSend"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy usando un cliente IRC llamado ATOMIC y este en el Editext que envía el mensaje tiene `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` pero me gustaría con un botón para realizar este evento.

Answer (score 0):

para ejecutar acciones al dar click a un botón existe el evento

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```